# How can I use token replacement for IElementCollection<TModel> property in message

Tags: exm, contact-facets

I created custom facet which has `IElementCollection<TModel>` property. `TModel` has properties: `Name`, `Value`.

**How can I implement token replacement in message, if I want to render `Value` of my `TModel` by `TModel` `Name` value.**

Also, I should have a possibility to see applied correct Value in Preview Mode for specific recipient.

I know how i can implement it for `string` facet property, but I don't have any idea how can I implement it for `IElementCollection` property.

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 Update-5 and Sitecore EXM 3.5

Any examples how can I implement it?

Comment: Have you considered using `IElementDictionary`? Just a suggestion, if you need to represent key-value pairs.

Comment: I can use it. But I still need an example

Comment: @AndreiPaliakou Could you give an example of the output you're looking for?

Comment: @AndreiPaliakou Did you find a solution to this and what have you tried so far? There is documentation on how to create a custom token, see https://doc.sitecore.net/email%20experience%20manager/configuring%20the%20delivery%20process/recipients/create%20a%20custom%20personalization%20token, but it's unclear if you're having problems with this approach

Comment: @JacobNielsen I already resolved this issue. I will add answer in few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to show some info from contact custom facet in message. I thought that I can resolve it with message tokens, but it's not try and will be difficult, as I see.

I found another way how can I do that. I used Message Personalization on my rendering where I wanted to show contact data. Before sending message, you must  check Personalization checkbox on Delivery Step:

[image]

It means that for each recipient EMX will render message for sending individually.

And now we can easily get recipientID from query string (**ec_recipient**) in your Action,  where it needed:

```
private Guid GetContactId()
        {
            var contactGuid = Guid.Empty;
            var recipientId = string.Empty;
            var recipientIdObj = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ec_recipient"];
            if (recipientIdObj != null)
            {
                recipientId = recipientIdObj;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(recipientId))
            {
                recipientId = recipientId.Replace("xdb:", string.Empty);
                ShortID shortRecipientId;
                if (ShortID.TryParse(recipientId, out shortRecipientId))
                    contactGuid = shortRecipientId.Guid;
            }
            else if(Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Contact != null)
            {
                contactGuid = Tracker.Current.Contact.ContactId;
            }

            return contactGuid != Guid.Empty ? contactGuid : Guid.Empty;
```

When you have contactId, you can find your contact, get data from contact facet,  return it in your Action and render contact data on View.